# from django.conf.urls import path,include, import error

Tags: python, django

I am creating a simple about me web page using django. I am getting error that cannot import name 'path'. I have python  3.6 installed on my machine and latest version of django is installed. Can anyone tell me the solution and what I'm doing wrong. I'm using Jinja template.  Is there any problem?

```
personal/urls.py

    from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    ]


mysite/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path(r'^index/', include('personal.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Please paste the full error also

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#simplified-url-routing-syntax . `django.conf.urls` should probably be `django.urls`.

Comment: I see you have django..conf.urls instead of django.conf.urls...

Is this normal?

Comment: from django.conf.urls import path, include

Comment: sorry that is a typo brother.....but still getting the same error

Comment: Please paste both your current code and your current error

Comment: i have edited my question.please look once

Comment: Using the URLconf defined in User.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
 1. ^admin/
 2. ^&
The empty path didn't match any of these.

=\
 
this is the error

Comment: You are mixing up the imports and syntax for `url()` and the new `path()`. Make sure you are using a tutorial/documentation for version of Django that you are using. If you are using Django 2.0 and `path()`, the correct import is `from django.urls import include, path` and you should use `path('', ...)` instead of `path(r'^$', ...)`. Similarly, you should use `path('index/', ...)` or `path('', ...)` for your includes, and if you use `path('index/', ...)` you should go to `localhost:8000/index/` to view the page instead of `localhost:8000/`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in your import.

Current version:

```
from django..conf.urls import path, include
```

Correct version:

```
from django.conf.urls import path, include
```

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: Using the URLconf defined in User.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
 1. ^admin/
 2. ^&
The empty path didn't match any of these.

=\

Answer (score 0):

I think you've a typo in your code. 
Line 2 in mysites/urls.py should be like this

`from django.conf.urls import path, include`

Comment: still getting the same error brother

Comment: Using the URLconf defined in User.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
 1. ^admin/
 2. ^&
The empty path didn't match any of these.

=\

Comment: As suggested by @Pitto, please edit your question with the error traceback that you're getting.